# Problema con la biblioteca math.h (Linux)

Tags: c, codeblocks

Estoy realizando un programa en C en el IDE Codeblocks en Linux y no se ejecutan las funciones que se encuentran en la biblioteca `math.h`, he mirado en Wikipedia y he introducido este comando en la terminal dentro de la carpeta en la que tengo el proyecto:

```
user@zorin:/media/user/Disco duro/Trabajos codeblocks/prueba$ gcc main.c -lm -o main
```

Después de introducir el comando, he entrado de nuevo al IDE y sigue apareciéndome el mismo error en el compilador:

```
/media/user/Disco duro/Trabajos codeblocks/prueba/main.c | 8 | referencia a `sqrt' sin definir
                                                               error: ld returned 1 exit status

        === Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

¿Qué tendría que hacer para que se puedan compilar estas funciones dentro del IDE?

Este es el código que tengo en `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float num = 3;
    printf("%f\n", num);
    printf("%f\n", sqrt(num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Incluistes los `include` correspondientes? Tienes que publicar tu `main.c`; sino es pura especulación.

Comment: @CandidMoe Ya tenía el include escrito en la cabecera del archivo main.c, que está localizado de la carpeta del proyecto. Lo único que hice fue ejecutar el comando.

Comment: ¿Podemos ver el código de `main.c`? No es que desconfiemos de ti, pero es lo mínimo para intentar reproducir el problema. Te invito a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras He actualizado la pregunta, ya he puesto el código.

Comment: Tienes que enlazar con la librería matemática. En Linux, es `-lm`.